# How to make a Bangladeshi phone number field in the model of django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, validation, django-models, django-forms

Is there any **package or widgets** to do so?

Example numbers:

`[+880][17][59219191], [+880][16][59219090]`

Here `[+880]` is country code, which is constant,

`[14]`,`[16]`,`[17]`...etc are service provider numbers

`[59219090]`,`[59219191]`...etc are third part of mobile numbers in Bangladesh.

Comment: You can store the number in CharField like this +880-17-12345678 then split this as your use case

Comment: Do you need this in template that show value by spliting country code, operator code etc?

Comment: yes actually that's what I want @ShafikurRahman

Comment: Can you give sample.. what is your expected output?

Comment: Sure why not? @ShafikurRahman

Comment: A Bangladeshi phone number field in my html that is generated from my model as forms.ModelForm

Answer (score 1):

You can use [django-phonenumber-field](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-phonenumber-field) and set `PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION` for your national.

Comment: Are you sure that it contains Bangladesh(BN) as a region?

Comment: I couldnt check right now but pretty sure it has. Can you try and let us know. @BlackBoxSql

Comment: It's using Google's library to manage phone number on Android, so yes, it handles any possible phone number on the planet.

Answer (score 0):

you can use phone number field as `CharField` then use widget in ModelForm fields. Take help from this to apply masking of filed [link](http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/phone/)